# Import Gmail or Google Contacts Using ASP.NET and OAuth 2.0

Tags: asp.net, gmail, oauth-2.0

I have to read gmail contacts using **Oauth 2.0** using asp.net
I was able to validate the user successfully using oauth 2.0 but not able to fetch the contacts.

There is one php code which does the same. Here is the reference to it
http://lookmywebpage.com/api/google/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-php-and-oauth-2-0/

Can anyone help me to do the same in asp.net?

Comment: Can you code you used to try this that didn't work

Comment: this code is in php and works fine and i have mentioned it here for refernce but i want this to be done in asp.net